# Sketch the solution curve that passes through $(0, -2)$. From this sketch, write the equation for the solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Based on the direction field of $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x + y$
[Direction Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuoas.png)

I drew a parabola but I can't quite reduce it to an equation. My best attempt was $y(x) = (x-2)^2 -4$ but that doesn't really check out.